# Select COUNT(column) from MYTABLE group by column doesn't work

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables in my SQL server like this:

- Subjects: IDsub01 NameSub01
- Teacher: IDTeacher01 NameTeacher01
- Exam: IDExam01 IDTeacher01 IDsub01
  Exam: IDExam02 IDTeacher01 IDsub01
  Exam: IDExam03 IDTeacher01 IDsub01

I want to collect data:

```
IDsub01    Namesub01    3
```

It mean the subject have IDsub01 have 3 exams made by IDTeacher01. I try this SQL statement but it doesn't work

```
SELECT 
    s.IDsub, s.NameSub, COUNT(t.IdTeacher) 
FROM 
    subjects s, teacher t, exam e 
WHERE 
    t.IdTeacher = e.IdTeacher 
    AND e.IDSubject = s.IDSubject 
    AND t.IDTeacher = "IDTeacher01" 
GROUP BY
    t.IDTeacher
```

I get error

> Column 's.NameSub' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Format your code properly.

Comment: Where do I begin?  Use proper `JOIN`.  It's been around for over 25 years.  `t.IDTeacher = "IDTeacher01"` will not work.  Those non-aggregated columns in `SELECT` must in in `GROUP BY`.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrong group by:

```
SELECT s.IDsub, s.NameSub, count(t.IdTeacher) 
FROM subjects s, teacher t, exam e 
WHERE t.IdTeacher = e.Is.IDsub, s.NameSubdTeacher 
     and e.IDSubject = s.IDSubject 
        and t.IDTeacher = 'IDTeacher01'
    group by  s.IDsub, s.NameSub
```

Anyway you should avoid old implicit join syntax based on where and use explicit join syntax:

```
    SELECT s.IDsub, s.NameSub, count(t.IdTeacher) 
    FROM subjects s
    INNER JOIN teacher t ON t.IdTeacher = e.Is.IDsub 
    INNER JOIN  exam e ON s.NameSubdTeacher and e.IDSubject
    WHERE  t.IDTeacher = 'IDTeacher01' 
    group by  s.IDsub, s.NameSub
```

And use single quote for literal strings.

Comment: And the string literal should be in single quotes, not double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error due to misspelled IDsub in select vs IDSubject in the joining condition. Also you have to use an aggregate function on each column that is enumerated in select excepting those that are in the "group by" clause.
The right clause may be:

```sql
SELECT s.IDSubject, s.NameSub, COUNT(t.IdTeacher) 
FROM subjects s, teacher t, exam e 
WHERE t.IdTeacher = e.IdTeacher 
    AND e.IDSubject = s.IDSubject 
    AND t.IDTeacher = 'IDTeacher01'
GROUP BY s.IDSubject, s.NameSub;
```

See the solution on http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d286a/4/0